# Help Please! Accidentally deleted /lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service

Tags: lightdm, 19.04

I accidentally deleted "/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service".

Apologies for the naive q - but is this bad?
And could anyone tell me the contents of the file so that I can re-create it

Running Ubuntu 19.04

Thanks very much

Comment: "Accidentally"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service` provided by the *lightdm* package in Ubuntu 19.04. To reinstall it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

Comment: Should that fail, the file is a simple text file which you could re-create if necessary.